# Modifying the first integer occurence in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a problem with a list of strings where I want to change the first integer occurence in each entry. The lines all look like this:

```
"    1ICE     MW    1   0.138   0.181   0.348"
```

I am interested in changing the integer after the MW, namely adding 3 to it, but leaving the whitespaces intact, like this:

```
 "    1ICE     MW    4   0.138   0.181   0.348"
```

Because I want to leave the white spaces intact, I cannot simply stringsplit, and because not every entry looks the same (the number before ICE increases, and the amount of whitespaces then can change) I cannot just simply replace the "1" with "4". E.g. other entries could look like

```
"  128ICE     MW  509   0.916   0.921   1.697"
```

so they would have a different amount of whitespace before the integer I want to change and at the start. Is there a way to do this with some kind of pattern recognition?

Comment: It is not the first integer, what about `1ICE`?

Comment: `ClearAll[f];
f = StringReplace[#, (ws1 :  Whitespace ~~ n : NumberString ~~ 
        ws2 : Whitespace) /; IntegerQ[ToExpression[n]] :> 
     StringJoin[ws1, ToString[3 + ToExpression[n]], ws2]] &;`?

Comment: @Kuba sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant the first integer occurence that is only surrounded by whitespace (and not immediately followed by letters).

Comment: @kglr thanks a lot, that seems to work :) (it only produces a small error, namely that if it is applied to a case where the number I want to shift changes to get an additional digit, e.g. 9 -> 12, I still retain the additional whitespace that would not be needed in this file format for 2-digit numbers) But I can fix that manually :)